# Output values in a list below a user defined amount - functions

Tags: python

Python programming problem for first year college kids.

Write a program that first gets a list of integers from input. The input begins with an integer indicating the number of integers that follow. Then, get the last value from the input, and output all integers less than or equal to that value.

Ex: If the input is:

5
50
60
140
200
75
100

the output is:

50
60
75

The 5 indicates that there are five integers in the list, namely 50, 60, 140, 200, and 75. The 100 indicates that the program should output all integers less than or equal to 100, so the program outputs 50, 60, and 75.

Such functionality is common on sites like Amazon, where a user can filter results.

Your code must define and call the following two functions:
def get_user_values()
def output_ints_less_than_or_equal_to_threshold(user_values, upper_threshold)

Utilizing functions will help to make your main very clean and intuitive.

Here's what I have:

```
n = int(input())
user_values =[]

def get_user_values():
    for i in range(n):
        num = int(input())
        user_values.append(num)
        upper_threshold=user_values[-1]
    return user_values, upper_threshold
 
def output_ints_less_than_or_equal_to_threshold(user_values, upper_threshold):
    user_values = [i for i in user_values if i <= user_values[-1]]
    print(*user_values, sep = "\n")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    user_values, upper_threshold = get_user_values()
    output_ints_less_than_or_equal_to_threshold(user_values, upper_threshold)
```

the output is correct for the example problem, but not for anything else.

Comment: The assignment does not ask for one number per line.  It wants all the numbers of one line.  Right?

Answer (score 0):

You went to all the trouble to separate the threshold value, and then you don't use it.  Change one line:

```
def output_ints_less_than_or_equal_to_threshold(user_values, upper_threshold):
    user_values = [i for i in user_values if i <= upper_threshold]
    print(*user_values, sep = "\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_user_values():

    for i in range(user_input):
        nums = int(input())
        user_values.append(nums)
    upper_threshold = int(input())
    return user_values, upper_threshold
    
def output_ints_less_than_or_equal_to_threshold(user_values, upper_threshold):
    for i in user_values:
        if i <= upper_threshold:
            user_values = i
        
            print(user_values)
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    user_input = int(input())
    user_values = []
    
    user_values, upper_threshold = get_user_values()
    output_ints_less_than_or_equal_to_threshold(user_values, upper_threshold)
```